# Firebird 2.5 C# запрос на вставку сразу в две таблицы через Execute block

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

подскажите как правильно объединить этот код в единую команду через execute block. [image: код сейчас]
Пробовал сделать так, но ругается на @.[image: как пробовал]
Пробовал и без execute statement,тоже не работает.
Не могу сообразить как объединить эти команды, и есть ли способ это сделать.

Вот код https://pastebin.com/mLDgwgjv

Comment: Приведите код текстом

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mLDgwgjv 

Вот код.

Comment: В вопрос его поместите, там кнопка "править" внизу есть

Answer (score 0):

[Firebird 2.5 Language Reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-dml-execblock.html) говорит что:

1. Должны быть правильно объявлены входные параметры. Там довольно специфичный синтаксис, если не сказать хуже.
2. Не все клиентские библиотеки поддерживают входные параметры у EXECUTE BLOCK

Если не получится после исправления синтаксиса, я бы рекомендовал вам рассмотреть другие варианты:

1. Написать нормальную хранимую процедуру.
2. Использовать не параметры, а подстановку строковых значений непосредственно в запрос.
3. Отказаться от идеи выполнения одним запросом. С точки зрения изоляции нет разницы между одним запросом на вставку или несколькими в одной транзакции.

Answer (score 0):

Уберите символ `@` из `.Parameters.AddWithValue`, но оставьте в тексте инструкции. Таковы особенности работы с параметрами для этого провайдера.